# XML ERROR: This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below

Tags: xml, xslt

Can anyone help me Im trying to learn designing an xml using xsl for my class, and im watching a video tutorial on youtube. I see and copy what he's typing and I saw that it works but when I run my own xml and xsl file on the browser it says...

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
```

this is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='Text/xsl' href='Places.xsl' ?>
<Philipppines_Place>
    <Places>
        <title>Philippines</title>
        <description>Country</description>
    </Places>
    <Places>
        <title>Russai</title>
        <description>Country</description>
    </Places>
</Philipppines_Place>
```

This is my xsl file

```
<xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8">
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/Philippines_Place">
<html>
<body>
    <xsl:for-each select="Places">
       <xsl:value-of select="title" /><br />
       <xsl:value-of select="description" /><br />
    </xsl:for-each> 
</body>   
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the proper XML declaration syntax in the form of `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` and you might have more success, although in the last few years browser vendors have closed the door to client-side XSLT for XML loaded from the file system, usually the browser console (F12 tends to open it) will show you a security error or warning that your stylesheet from the local file system has not been loaded.